# I need help calculating the probability of winning a game from a television show.

Tags: probability

You have 20 different numbers, from zero to 99 and chosen randomly. The host of the show shows you the first number and asks you to guess if the next number is higher or lower than the first. Once you choose if it is higher or lower, it shows you the second number, if you got it right, you continue with the next number (guessing if the third is higher or lower than the second, and so on), if not, then you lose the game. If you hit all 19 times, you win the game.

What is the probability of winning the game?

P.S. sorry for the bad english

[image]

Edit: you have to assume that you choose with the best strategy to win.

Comment: what have you tried? The probability also depends on what strategy you take when playing the game.

Comment: I did a simulation and got 2207 sucesses out of a million, by always assuming the next number will be 50.5

Comment: @Empy2:  you can do slightly better by assuming the next number will be the median of the remaining numbers.  If the first ten numbers are all below 50 you should assume the eleventh is 54.5.  Of course, that is quite unlikely, so the corrections will in fact be small.  I am surprised the success rate is that high.  My gut clearly underestimates the advantage when the last number is close to the end.  A nit:  as the numbers start at 0 you should assume 49.5

Comment: @Empy2 I'm still confused. Suppose the first number shown is $30$. Naturally you'll guess that the second number will be higher, which will occur with probability $69/100$. Now suppose the host reveals that the second number is $60$ and so you'll guess that the third number will be lower. This will occur will probability $60/100$. Am I misinterpreting this probability experiment here?

Comment: You have two chances of 60/100, from 39 and 60, but only one chance of 80/100, from 80

Comment: In the continuous limit, and after the first few turns.  Take real numbers between $-1$ and $1$.  The pdf of a number being chosen, given continued success, is proportional to $1/(1+|x|)$, and the geometric mean of probability of success in one step is $1/\sqrt2$.  That would predict overall success of $2^{-9.5}=0.00138$

Comment: The arithmetic mean for one step in the previous comment is $1/\ln4$, giving an overall probability of $0.002097$

Comment: @MatthewPilling on second thoughts, I think your explanation is best, you should undelete it.

Comment: @Empy2 Are you sure? I'm getting a probability of around $0.004$

Comment: @Empy2 you are correct. Let $E_1$ be the event that you progress from the first to second round, $E_2$ the event that you progress from the second to third round, $X\in \{0,1,\ldots, 99\}$ the first number that appears, and $Y\in \{0,1,\ldots 99\}$ the second number that appears. Then $$P(E_2|E_1)=\sum_{x,y}P(E_2|E_1,X=x,Y=y)P(X=x,Y=y|E_1)$$ On one hand, $x\leq 48$ and $x+1 \leq y \leq 49$ then $$P(E_2|E_1,X=x,Y=y)=\frac{99-y}{100}$$ $$P(X=x,Y=y|E_1)=\frac{1}{100}\cdot \frac{1}{99-x}$$

Comment: On the other hand, if $x\leq 49$ and $y\geq 50$ then  $$P(E_2|X=x,Y=y)=\frac{y}{100}$$ $$P(X=x,Y=y|E_1)=\frac{1}{100}\cdot \frac{1}{99-x}$$ So using some symmetry we get $$P(E_2|E_1)=2\cdot \Bigg(\sum_{x=0}^{48}\sum_{y=x+1}^{49}\frac{99-y}{100^2(99-x)} + \sum_{x=0}^{49}\sum_{y=50}^{99}\frac{y}{100^2(99-x)}\Bigg) \approx 0.7166$$ But $P(E_1)=0.745$ so we cannot conclude that $P(E_1 \cap E_2)=\big(P(E_1)\big)^2$